# Perfomance testing for XMPP Chat application with Jmeter & Blazemeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, xmpp, performance-testing, blazemeter

We are trying to do a performance testing for a XMPP-based mobile chat application using Jmeter and Blazemeter.

As we are new to XMPP web-services.
Can anyone brief us how to use Jmeter or Blazemeter for XMPP and how to record the scripts using XMPP plugin?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked for any JMeter plugins compatible with the protocol you're trying to use?

Comment: @RaGe, Yes we  found yandex plugin by refering to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680276/testing-xmpp-chat-server-with-jmeter ,  However we didnt understand how this yandex is used with Jmeter .   We are  doing R &D on VSTS with E-eux for mobile apps.  We didnt exact picture how to implement the yandex with Jmeter  .Can you please guide us . how to do performance testing for mobile app .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to try use [tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) instead?

- originally created for load-testing [Jabber/XMPP servers](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/features.html#jabber-xmpp-related-features) although supports a lot of other protocols at the moment;
- has better performance on the same load-generation servers amount than Jmeter: you will get instantly higher load on the same amount of hardware used;
- ready for distributed load-generation.

- [Benchmark Approach: Jabber/XMPP](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/benchmark.html#jabber-xmpp)
- [Load testing Ejabberd XMPP Server with Tsung](http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/12/load-testing-ejabberd-xmpp-server-with.html)
- [Load testing Tigase XMPP Server with Tsung](https://projects.tigase.org/boards/4/topics/1910)
- [Introduction to Load Testing with Tsung](https://github.com/lavrin/euc-2014)
- [Tsung questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsung)

Comment: @Belik, Thanks for your valuable info..we have started with Tsung . The above links are really helpful for us

Comment: @Belik, Using TSUNG we were able to test  xmpp protocol performance successfully . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @PrabhakarY, nice to read it. Good luck with Tsung.